# C++ sleep time for alphabet equivalent numerical code

Tags: c++

**2nd EDIT Details added with change code**

I have an alphabet equivalent numerical code in array of string that I want to be output when a word OR sentence is input. Here is my c++ code for that. It gets user input & output a beep for equivalent time for all numerical digit for all alphabets in a full word like morse code would do. Basically I need this for my embedded application but 1st I want to have it working in typical C then I move it to embedded.

Currently it works like e.g. alphabet 'i' has numerical code 24, when executed & 'i' is given as input, it beeps first two times with a sleep time of INNER_LOOP between those i.e. 450. Then it sleeps for OUTER_LOOP i.e. 700 and then beeps for 4 times with INNER_LOOP sleep time. So it is possible to recognize that it beeps 2 times, wait & then beeps 4 times  i.e. transmitting '24' that is code for 'i'. If I input 'ii' it does same twice i.e. starts beep for 2nd 'i' after INNER_LOOP sleep time so code appears like 2424. It's not possible to recognize it was was 24 & again 24. It should work like 24 read as described before than a looooong wait & 24 again raed, so user may recognize code for two alphabets i.e. 'ii' or any other combination.

What I want it to introduce a THIRD_SLEEP time that occurs between any two alphabets of same word so that each alphabet code can be read separately. Currently it's only between numerical code of same alphabet.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

string texttopattern(char c)
{
//Hello world again
//125-15-123-123-135 1346-135-1235-123-145 1-1245-1-24-1345

    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwqyz"; //osv
    string code[] = {"1","12","14","145", "15", "124", "1245",
                      "125", "24", "245", "13", "123", "134",
                      "1345", "135", "1234", "12345", "1235", "234", "2345",
                      "136", "1236", "1346", "13456", "1356", "12346"};
    int index = alphabet.find(c);
    if(index!=-1)
        return code[index];
    else
        return " ";
}

int main()
{
    const int OUTER_SLEEP = 700,
              INNER_SLEEP = 450;
    int n;
    string ord;
    getline(cin, ord);
    string code="";
    for(int i=0; i<ord.length(); i++)
    {
        code += texttopattern(ord[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<code.length(); i++)
    {
        n = code[i] - '0';
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            cout<<'\a';
            Sleep(INNER_SLEEP);
        }
        Sleep(OUTER_SLEEP);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, it makes your code unnecessarily confusing having the `for( int i...` loop nested inside a `for( int i...` loop.

Comment: inner lop is to iterate for number of times the numerical value of code bec I need manipulation for each iteration

Comment: Yes, but it would be more readable to use a different name for the inner variable (or a range based loop for the outer one)

Comment: I change it to j for inner loop

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array `string code[]` has the beep times for the corresponding letters and you want a long static sleep time after each character processed; you may declare constant sleep time as:

```
const int STATIC_SLEEP = 2000;
const int STATIC_SLEEP_INNER = 2000;
```

And your code could be:

```
string str = "your string for morse code";
for(char ch: str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<code[ch-'a']; i++)
    {
        cout<<'\a';
        Sleep(STATIC_SLEEP_INNER);
    }
Sleep(STATIC_SLEEP);
}
```

Comment: introducing a 2nd sleep in outer loop help me to recognize code sequence for a single alphabet.I add detail to OP & change code adding a 2nd sleep as suggested by you here.The problem is how do it is recognized now numeral code for 2nd alphabet starts in a word.I need another SLEEP time that occurs when code for one alphabet is finished. Please read OP where I detailed. Thank you for so far help.

Comment: @enterprize the outer sleep will be called after the beep for one alphabet finishes.

Comment: no, it's called after finishing each numeral in code like as I explained in OP.24 is code for 'i',OUTER_LOOP is executed between 2 & 4. Inner sleep is called between beeps for 2 and 4. LIKE 
"beep-Inner_SLEEP-Beep(i.e.2)-OUTER_LOOP-beep-Inner_SLEEP-beep-Inner_SLEEP-beep-Inner_SLEEP-beep (i.e.4)"

Comment: @enterprize you will have to multiply the inner loop terminating condition by a factor as the loop iterations will not wait for the beep to end. or add an inner sleep as i have modified. You will have to fine tune the inner sleep time so that you do not et a pause between successive inner beeps.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate ASCII equivalent of a certain character and pass it into Sleep function. For Example :

```
for(int i = 0; i<code.length(); i++){
          n = code[i] - '0';
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
              cout<<'\a';
              int ASCVal = code[i] - '0';
              int standardSleepTime = 600; // you can assign your standard sleep time here.
              Sleep(standardSleepTime);
              Sleep(ASCVal);//Now Sleep time for each character will be different

   }}
```

If you think this interval is low, then you can multiply ASCVal by 10 to increase the sleep time.You need do this -

```
 int standardSleepTime = 600; // you can assign your standard sleep time here.
 Sleep(standardSleepTime);
 int ASCVal = ( (code[i]-'0') * 10);
 Sleep(ASCVal);
```

Comment: I think I did not describe problem well. e.g for a word 'hello', 'h' has a code then 'e' has a code & follows.I want that code for 'h' should have standard sleep time & then a long sleep and code for 'e' starts with standard sleep time for it code & long sleep and code for 'l' starts with standard sleep time & it follows whole word.What I want is differentiate between alphabets of a full word.So I may know code for 'h' finished & for 'e' starts & as follows.

Comment: Yes I understand you question. You can see that, my code uses different sleep time for different character. I think you haven't understand my code. Please see the sleep portion of my code. Hope you will get it now. Please see my edited post.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I edited OP with change in code & also reworded to make more clear, plz read OP.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand you. What do you mean by OP?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line:

```
 string code="";
```

with

```
vector<int> code;
```

so you store a list of integers instead of a big long string of representations of integers.

That is:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    string ord;
    getline(cin, ord);
    std::vector<int> code;
    for(int i=0; i<ord.length(); i++)
    {
        code.push_back(atoi(texttopattern(ord[i])));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<code.length(); i++){
        Sleep(600); //same sleep time for all alphabets of a word,  
                         //I want to add long sleep time before code for new 
                         //alphabets stats  

        Sleep(code[i]); // sleep for length of time according to code book
        // or Beep(code[i]); // if you want to Beep for the appropriate length
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note the use of atoi() above to translate your texttopattern() into an int so that Sleep can accept it. If the string is not an integer (eg "") atoi will return 0 (resulting in no Sleep)

I may have misunderstood your question. Previous interpretation was:

If you don't have a mapping of characters to "sleep times" (or other values), you could do (assuming all lower-case):

```
#include <unistd.h>
// .. other setup stuff ...
int factor = 1;
for (int i=0; str[i] != 0; i++) {
    sleep( factor * ('z' - str[i]) );
```

that is, sleep for whatever displacement the character has from the character 'z', and in this case, sleep for 1 times that distance in seconds. E.g. for the character 'y' in the code, sleep for 1 second. For the letter 'x' sleep for 2 seconds.

Otherwise you could set up a std::map of input characters to 'sleep time' values.

If you want to add a pause between a beep for each character, and each character treated equally, perhaps:

```
void make_word_audible(const char *word) {
    int character_beep_len = 1;
    int charater_pause_beep_len = 2;
    int space_character_beep_len = 4;

    for (int i=0; str[i] != 0; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') // space == long beep
            beep(space_character_beep_len);
        else
            beep('z' - str[i]);

        beep(space_character_beep_len);
    }
    // end of word:

}
```

and if none of the above, consider actually translating characters to morse code, where you vary your input to you beep function and your sleep(int seconds) (pause) function.

Comment: can you please see the OP once again.I have tried to make it bit clear what I want & code is also updated.Sleep time has no relation with code of alphabets.It's only to distinguish between 1stly numeral codes of same alphabet like between 123,& 2ndly between codes of a word like between 123 & 456 e.g. as one word contain many alphabets.These two things are working fine now,may be u run this code on urself to see.Now I want a sleep time between words, so that it a word comprising of say 123,456,789 codes & another of 987,654,321 have sleep between so diff words r distinguished